# Can I control the shutter speed of a photo from an iPod Touch 4th gen?

Tags: ipod-touch, ios, software-recommendation, camera

Is there a Camera app that will let me control the shutter speed of a 4th gen iPod Touch? Camera+ for some reason doesn't support this.

Edit: I mean shutter speed, not exposure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tap on an area of the picture you are taking to adjust the image settings (including the exposure) to that area of the image.

Answer (score 0):

Photoshop Express has this feature.

Photoshop express is also free.

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/adobe-photoshop-express/id331975235?mt=8

Comment: Isn't this post-shot? The OP was asking for more fine control over exposure, and specifically didn't want post processing. Good to have the link tho.

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. Didn't understand the question (My answer was before he said that).

Answer (score 0):

Threads like [this one](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/55077-choose-your-shutter-speed-iphone-camera.html) suggest that direct control of the "shutter" speed is impossible, as Apple have not released such controls in their API.

(Obviously, there's no actual shutter on the iPhone)